# Flash CS5.5 adds green background to bitmaps with alpha

Tags: flash, background, bitmap, alpha

Recently, my Flash began to behave weirdly. I have imported PSD file, where were some layers with transparency. They imported successfully and are OK.

The problem is, when I want to edit them from library with PS. I always worked great, but now flash adds all pixels with alpha green background color (see picture below).

[Left: Bitmap with alpha; Right: after clicking on "Edit with ..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH83l.png)

I went through all the settings I've found, but I can't find any solution. Did this happen to you too? Did you solve it?

Thank you for your answers.

## EDIT: SOLUTION

I've resetted to the default settings. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/992810

Comment: If you're using actionscript, try [floodFill()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#floodFill()), otherwise just add a layer at the bottom and draw a rectangle with no stroke and a green fill. Off topic: you can probably recreate the glow/inner shadow effects in Flash and keep all the work as vectors which will probably drop filesize consierably.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem. I am using 'Edit with Photoshop' feature a lot and editing images with alpha channel is pretty crucial for me. Also, when my colleagues use it, it works perfectly for them.

Comment: the floodFill option happens at runtime, so after you're colleagues updated the psd and you load it, the floodfill should replace transparent white to green (if you specify the right parameters) when the swf runs, but leave the psd loaded asset intact. similarly if your fla has the bottom most layer as a flat green background, anything on top with transparency will appear to have a green background. I don't think I understand your problem well enough

Comment: I've finally found the solution, but thank you for your ideas.

Comment: well done. would be nice to share your solution as an answer with the rest of the community for documentation purposes

Comment: I've already did that, it just wasn't highlighted enough :)